# for loop won't iterate inside def block

Tags: function, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

So I have run all of these def functions independently in the shell with no errors and I have gone step by step through the debugger to ensure that all values are assigned correctly.

Thus far I cannot see an error in the code yet when I run it, the second **for** loop within the `displayASCII` block will always display only one underscore (despite the `fullWord` value evaluating properly to a random word within the `words` dictionary.

For some reason the **for** loop just quits after after one iteration with `i` at `0`.

```
import random
HANGMANPICS = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
words = {"Easy":"blah1 blah2 blah3".split(),
         "Medium":"blah4 blah5 blah6".split(),
         "Hard":"blah7 blah8 blah9".split()}

def getRandomWord(wordDict, difficulty):
    wordKey = difficulty
    wordGrab = random.randint(0, len(wordDict[wordKey]) - 1)
    return [wordDict[wordKey][wordGrab]]

def displayASCII(HANGMANPICS, wrongGuesses, rightGuesses, fullWord):
    print(HANGMANPICS[len(wrongGuesses)])
    print()

    print("Missing letters:", end= " ")
    for guess in wrongGuesses:
        print(guess, end = " ")
    print()

    blanks = "_" * len(fullWord)
    for i in range(len(fullWord)):
        print("_", end = " ")
    print()

    for i in range(len(fullWord)):
        if fullWord[i] in rightGuesses:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + fullWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]

            for x in blanks:
                print(x, end=" ")
            print()

def getGuess(alreadyGuessed):

    while True:
        print("Guess a letter.")
        guess = input()
        guess = guess.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print("Just ONE letter, cheater.")
        elif guess in alreadyGuessed:
            print("Maybe something you HAVEN'T already tried.")
        elif guess not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            print("How about a LETTER big guy")
        else:
            return guess

def chooseDifficulty(listOfKeys):
    counter = 0
    for i in listOfKeys:
        print(str(counter) + ":" + str(i))
        counter += 1
    difficulty = input("Choose a difficulty (0, 1 or 2): ")
    while difficulty not in "0 1 2".split():
            difficulty = input("Choose a difficulty (0, 1 or 2): ")
    print("Difficulty set to: " + listOfKeys[int(difficulty)])
    return listOfKeys[int(difficulty)]


print("H A N G M A N")
wrongGuesses = ""
rightGuesses = ""
keys = list(words.keys())
difficulty = chooseDifficulty(keys)
fullWord = getRandomWord(words, difficulty)

while True:
    displayASCII(HANGMANPICS, wrongGuesses, rightGuesses, fullWord)

    guess = getGuess(wrongGuesses + rightGuesses)
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out `len(fullWord)` before the loop to see what it is?

Comment: No, I just did, the length evaluates to 1 but the word prints to be an entire word.

Comment: Try it again. :-) I'm pretty sure `len(fullWord)` is always going to be 1. (Hint: `getRandomWord` is returning something a bit odd.)

Comment: Thanks so much that is my problem.  After two hours of searching and creating an account just to post that.... I'll take my dunce cap now, fine sir.

Comment: Okay so I've just run through it again and I may have been to hasty to accept that as the issue.  `getRandomWord` so far as I can tell is returning a string from `words` however it IS evaluating to a length of 1.  I'm so far down the rabbit hole by now.  What am I missing?

Comment: `getRandomWord` is retuning a list with exactly one element.

Comment: You were right, the issue was an extra set of `[]` enclosing the return value of that def block.  Thanks again, sorry to flip-flop on understanding xD